# How do I do a MongoDB left join, keeping documents with no match on the right?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm a little new to this, so forgive me if this is actually trivial. I'm trying to do a left outer join in MongoDB/NodeJS. I would like all matching documents from the left table, even if they have no match on the right. I have a collection of questions:

```
{_id: 'question1', text: 'This is a question.'}
{_id: 'question2', text: 'This is another question.'}
```

And a collection of responses, each tied to a user and a question:

```
{_id: 'response1', QID: 'question1', UID: 'player1', response: 'This is my answer.'}
```

Now, I'd like to get a list of questions and a user's response to each one, including ones where there is no recorded response, so what I'd want from the documents above might be...

```
{_id: 'question1', text: 'This is a question.', response: {_id: 'response1', QID: 'question1', UID: 'player1', response: 'This is my answer'}}
{_id: 'question2', text: 'This is another question.', response: []}
```

Is there a way to do this in the aggregation pipeline? When I use lookup to join responses to questions, and then match the UID, the second question disappears because there's no response tied to it (and thus, fails to satisfy the UID match).

Edit: another thing I tried was to use a let/pipeline in the lookup stage:

```
const month = 11;
const year = 2020;
const UID = 'aaaaaaa';
//Only get responses by UID 'aaaaaaa'
const myResponses = await Question.aggregate([
    { $match: { year, month } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: Response.collection.name,
        let: { questionID: '$_id' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [{ $eq: ['$$questionID', '$QID'] }, { $eq: ['$UID', UID] }],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
        as: 'Response',
      },
    },
```

This was close, but for some reason, matching the UIDs doesn't seem to work, as it returns an empty array for the Response on every clue. Taking out the last $eq condition and just matching $$questionID and $QID gets every response to every question, as I would've expected, but trying to check for equality to a constant isn't working.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/ per the docs

> Performs a left outer join

Comment: This is the document that I looked at, but the problem is that unmatched documents don't show up in the results. I would like for a document on the left data set to show up, even if there is no match on the right side.

Comment: Add a sample document and a query that does not return it to the question in mongo shell format.